# How to merge two GitHub accounts

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub accounts, one of this was created a long time ago at my work and has an username that refers to the company where I work.

I have another account which is my personal GitHub account that I can't stop using.

Could I merge the two accounts so I can work in only one of these?

Comment: you must delete one account and transfer all repo to other https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/

Comment: Yes, you can Transfer ownership to another account goto Setting >>Transfer ownership

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Merging 2 accounts is not possible at github, you can transfer ownership to your personal account.

```
goto  >> Setting >>Transfer ownership
```

For more details : https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/

Comment: Hi @RodrigoCurbelo  if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: But, if I transfer the ownership of all in my work account to my personal account, all the logs (like commits, pull requests, issues, etc) will get under my personal account? And, will I get access to the private organization of my company automatically? What will I exactly lose?

Comment: I mean, the repos which I have access in my company account wasn't created by me, I am just a collaborator there... will I get exactly all the same in my personal account?

Comment: Hi MohammadFarad - I don't know if you're still online and checking SO - but if so, I do believe that now (five years later, in 2021!) this accepted answer has become misleading, given @ScottMathson's detailed answer of what you can do - almost everything you'd want to! - below. I wonder if you had time to add link to it - if you agree with me, of course! Many thanks.

Answer (score 38):

Responding with updated answer here (relevant in 2019).

Luckily this is a relatively quick process to **1) transfer repo ownership**, **2) manage (add/remove/change) account email addresses**, and **3) keep/transfer *most* commit history to the profile’s contribution graph**.

**Transferring repository ownership** only requires a few steps.

- From Repo > Settings page > Options > scroll to the bottom, looking for red-colored “Transfer” button within the “Danger Zone”
- Fill out the required fields, typing the name of the repository to confirm and entering the new owner’s GH username
- New owner receives an email with an auth token that expires after 24 hours. Be sure to check that email for the account you’re transferring to and follow the link to fully complete any repo transfers

Repo transfers between accounts includes all issues, pull requests, forks, stars, alongside automatic redirects being setup for git and http. Though you should update your remote’s origin URL once the transfer is complete: `git remote set-url origin new_url`

Git commit history, SAML, and other items are tied to the email(s) you have on-file within GitHub and in your remote, local setup. Keeping/transferring commit history to contribution graph comes when you **add original, authoring email/verify it** on user account you're consolidating/merging into.

- From GH dashboard > Click your profile photo dropdown > Settings page
- Click on Emails in the left sidebar > Add email address field > Add new email
- Check your inbox for the email address you’ve just added and click the link included. You should land on your GitHub dashboard, seeing an email verification confirmation banner

Previous note about *most* history transferring is referring to PRs and issues which fall under this "grey area" of history and will not transfer when combining accounts.

After you've added email to GH user account + verified it, most commit history will transfer. Allow GitHub a bit of time to propagate the history and contributions between accounts.

You will lose commits tied to original pull requests and issues histories tied to account you're removing. These “*...would instead be attributed to our “Ghost” user once the account is deleted, though the issues/PRs themselves would otherwise be unaffected*.” (from GH Support). If you're looking to read more, I wrote up a quick blog article for this with steps and visuals on transferring repo ownership, adding emails, and more - [how to merge/combine two (or many) GitHub user accounts](https://scottmathson.com/blog/2019/02/13/combine-merge-github-user-accounts-keeping-git-commit-history/?ref=stack-overflow).

GitHub does recommend using one user account for personal and professional (work) repositories ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/types-of-github-accounts#personal-user-accounts)), definitely consider doing so!

Managing multiple user accounts can be cumbersome, though there are ways to simplify workflow of multiple accounts, though, so in the case this response wasn't for you and you want to keep your many accounts as-is, see [how to manage multiple GH accounts on one machine with SSH keys](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca?gi=271243503674).

Comment: you should make it clear that the links you're posting are your own.

Comment: Tried to make that apparent, @Jean-FrançoisFabre
"_If you're looking to read more, **I wrote up a quick blog article for this** with steps and visuals on transferring repo ownership, adding emails, and more..._". Thanks for your feedback, though, am new to contributing here! :)

Comment: right. This answer was detected by a bot because it had a self-promotion pattern because of the link matching your username. But it's okay.

Comment: @ScottMathson My GitHub work account has commits in a repository owned by my company. Can I transfer those commits' history to my personal account as well?

Comment: Thanks for this. One missing step is to also transfer Gists. It's an easy thing to forget, and I lost some private Gists associated with the deleted account.

Comment: I'm getting "email is already in use" when I try to add the e-mail of the second account. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: In my experience, it is better to have separate personal and private accounts. For example: you might have a Github Action that needs to clone another private repo of the organization. The solution to date is to add the personal token as a secret to the repo. If you have a single account, you are granting your coworkers to clone your personal repositories, I do not think that is what you want to achieve. This is just an example, just to warn you that there are some "real-case" scenarios that, even if they are bad practises, you might be forced to do in your work place.

Comment: Hey, does this also transfer commit contributions made using Github's private email?

Answer (score 11):

While Github outlines a limited "[Merging multiple user accounts](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-multiple-user-accounts/)" process, which is also mentioned in previous answers, it is not a complete solution. It does not resolve ownership in third party repositories contributions.

GitHub will display comments from a deleted user (which will be the account you got rid of following GitHub's account merge suggestion) as "ghost" user's comments - without attributing them to the surviving account. See some more details here:

https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-your-user-account/

So in reality as of November 2016 there is no general way to fully merge **all** contributions from one account to another.

Comment: the accepted answer is no longer truly correct, as a "merge" doesn't exist and also assumes you own the repositories. However if you have a work account and wanted to merge that to your personal so your private commits are tracked.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub has a convenient command-line tool: `hub` found at https://hub.github.com

I've written an example to move all repos from all your organisations to `my_new_organisation_name`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

orgs="$(hub api '/user/orgs' | jq -r '.[] | .login')";
repos="$(for org in $orgs; do hub api '/orgs/'"$org"'/repos' | jq -r '.[] | .name';
         done)"

for org in $orgs; do
    for repo in $repos; do
        ( hub api '/repos/'"$org"'/'"$repo"'/transfer'
                  -F 'new_owner'='my_new_organisation_name' | jq . ) &
    done
done
```

For users rather than organisation, set `my_new_organisation_name` to the replacement username, remove the outer loop, and replace the `repos=` line with:

```bash
repos="$(hub api /users/SamuelMarks/repos | jq -r '.[] | .name')"
```

EDIT: Found a [GUI](https://github.com/floe/github-bulk-editor) if you prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54549899