# How to transfer all repos and commits (activity) from one github account to another?

Tags: github

I have a github account `account_A` to which I had lost access in 2018. Since, I've been working on a separate account `acount_B`.

Recently, I regained access of `account_A` and would like to fill in its beautiful activity graph with everything I've ever commited to `acount_B`. How can I do this?

edit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693255/how-to-merge-two-github-account) suggests 'adding a new email' to the account to which I'd like to merge my commit history. However, it shows 'email already in use', because it is being used in my other account (from which I'd like to transfer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two GitHub accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693255/how-to-merge-two-github-accounts)

Comment: the post suggests adding the email for the account but once I try it, it says 'email already in use'. It is the email I'm using in the account I'd like to merge from.

Comment: You'll need to delete the account you no longer want to use. `acount_B` will have to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did (p.s, you will need access to both accounts)

1. Add your new account as a contributor on the repo(s) you wish to transfer.
2. Create a new repository on your new account. The name doesn't necessarily need to be the same.
3. In your local copy of the repo on the 'original/old' account, open the terminal and set the new git push url to the new account's repo address.

You can run to view the current repo url:

`git remote get-url --all origin`

Run to update the repo's url:

`git remote set-url origin <new-repository-URL>`

4. Finally, git push to upload the project files to the new repository address on the new account.